# Show drop down list value between max and min value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down box and the values in a drop down box is not consistent. Example - getting the max and min value from the database and showing the values from max to min into the drop down. like the min value is 3 and max is 7, so the values that will be shown is 3,4,5,6,7.
That is what I am thinking but how to implement or call the function in the drop down, Can someone help me in details,struggling with this part from last night,

```
MaxMinSkillLevel minMax = CompetencyManager.GetMaxAndMinSKillLevelBySkillName(lblname.Text);


        //    List<string> DDLlist = new List<string>();
        //    for (int i = Int32.Parse(minMax.minimumLevel); i < Int32.Parse(minMax.maximumLevel); i++)
        //    {
        //        DDLlist.Add((i + 1).ToString());

        //    }
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: when you query the database, are you applying 'order by' clause just so that you dont get in different order? can you show the definition of CompetencyManager.GetMaxAndMinSKillLevelBySkillName ?

Comment: Yes I did order by and sorry I wrote the method name wrong, this is the method  public static     GetLevelRangeByCompetency_Result GetLevelRangeByCompetency(int competencyID)
        {
            GetLevelRangeByCompetency_Result result = new GetLevelRangeByCompetency_Result();
            if ((result = CompetencyDAO.GetLevelRangeByCompetency(competencyID)) == null)
            {
                result.MinLevel = "0";
                result.MaxLevel = "0";
            }

            return result;
        }

Comment: Don't put in comment if you want to amend your question, instead, edit your own post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly.

On your page load you could do something like this:

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

        if (DDLlist==null)
        {
          MaxMinSkillLevel minMax = CompetencyManager.GetMaxAndMinSKillLevelBySkillName(lblname.Text);

          DDLlist = new List<string>();
          for (int i = Int32.Parse(minMax.minimumLevel); i < Int32.Parse(minMax.maximumLevel); i++)
          {
            DDLlist.Add((i + 1).ToString());
          }
        }
     // Load data for the DropDownList control only once, when the 
     // page is first loaded.
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {

        // Specify the data source
        YourDropDownList.DataSource = DDLlist;

        // Bind the data to the control.
        YourDropDownList.DataBind();

        // Set the default selected item, if desired.
        YourDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MaxMinSkillLevel minMax = CompetencyManager.GetMaxAndMinSKillLevelBySkillName(lblname.Text);
int min = Int32.Parse(minMax.minimumLevel);
int max = Int32.Parse(minMax.maximumLevel);

//Enumerable.Range(start, count)
List<int> skills = Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min) + 1).ToList();

skillsDropDown.DataSource = skills;
skillsDropDown.DataBind();
```